# Custom content type naming convention should we use plural or singular names

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, administration, communication-site, custom-content-type

I want to create a custom content type inside our SharePoint communication site, but I am not sure if the name should be Plural or Singular?

When I look at the built-in content types names, I found some are singular (such as Event) and some are plural (Users).

So what should be the naming convention for any custom content type?

[image]

Comment: I am not sure who is the genius that close this question,, it got one answer and it is approved... so why it was closed? i am asking about naming convention and not asking for opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use singular name for your custom content types in SharePoint online communication sites.

When you add the custom content type in your SharePoint online list and click on "New" button to create a new list item based on custom content type, it shows the name of your content type.

As you are creating a single list item, content type name should be singular.

**For example**:

It should be shown as:

```
New > Announcement
```

[image]

And *not* like:

```
New > Announcements
```

Comment: ok make sense to me